# What will happen , if i will comment onStartCommand during writing a service?

Tags: android, service

I am trying to start an Android service code and i have commented onStartCommand , so do the service will keep running or it will stop itself in the middle way.

**MyCode:**

```
@Override 
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{

  //super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

  return START_STICKY;
```

}

Please let me know , the possible situation during service running in the system.

Answer (score 0):

No problem, service will star and run.
but if you want to initialize or start/call some function on start of your service override onStartCommand and return START_STICKY if you want your service to never die(want this service to continue running until it is explicitly stopped, so return sticky.)
OR return NOT_STICKY if you want to let your service die after work
Links: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: wow great but i used many time but i find out when lock the tablet after 7-8 hrs , when i open , i can see no more service is running.

Answer (score 0):

If you start a service via `onStartCommand()`, then that service will only stop if you call `stopSelf()` or `stopService()` or if system decides to destroy your service for some reason. If system destroys the service, then it will attempt to restart based on the return value of `onStartCommand()` like `STICKY`, `NON_STICKY`, `REDELIVER_INTENT`

But it looks like you don't understand the basics of Service component. Please catch up on the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) first on the basics of components esp. `Service` in this case.